# Trying to create azure storage account & use the same to store terraform state file

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

on the way to create aks via terraform, here i want to create azure storage account & want to use the same same account to store the terraform state file.

however getting below error

│ Error: Error loading state: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name": storage.AccountsClient#ListKeys: Invalid input: autorest/validation: validation failed: parameter=accountName constraint=MaxLength value="azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name" details: value length must be less than or equal to 24
│

```
#Create Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
  location = "${var.location}"
  name     = "${var.global-prefix}-${var.cluster-id}-${var.environment}-azwe-aks-rg"
}

#Create Storage Account & Container
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_acc" {
  name                     = "${var.cluster-id}-storage-account"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS" 
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storage_container" {
  name                  = "${var.cluster-id}-storage-account-container"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_acc.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

#store terraform state in remote container
terraform {
  # Configure Terraform State Storage
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name"
    storage_account_name = "azurerm_storage_container.storage_acc.name"
    container_name       = "azurerm_storage_container.storage_container.name"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78tG6.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first create the storage account and container then while creating the aks cluster you need to give the below:

```
terraform {
  # Configure Terraform State Storage
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name"
    storage_account_name = "azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name"
    container_name       = "powermeprodtfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

Instead of creating the storage account and container ins the same file while storing the terraform tfstate.

**Example:**

**Create storage account and container:**

```
provider "azurerm" { 
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "resourcegroupname"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "yourstorageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS" 
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "terraform"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}
```

[image]

Then create the aks resource group and store the tfstate in container.

```
provider "azurerm" { 
  features {}
}
terraform {
  # Configure Terraform State Storage
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "resourcegroup"
    storage_account_name = "storageaccountnameearliercreated"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks_rg" {
 name = "aks-rg"
 location = "west us"
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to store the Terraform state file in Azure Storage. » Jorge Bernhardt](https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/terraform-backend-azure/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20store%20the%20Terraform%20state%20file,created%20in%20the%20previous%20step%2C%20you...%20More%20)

Comment: I want to create storage account along with container and want to store the state file, i have updated the code, seems some issue, i think its not possible to pass the value using variable backend "azurerm" {}

Comment: Hello @SatyamPandey, Unfortunately that's not possible as the terraform backend will need storage account's credentials to store the tfstate. but as you are creating it simultaneously it errors out telling cannot find the keys

Comment: backend can be only passed when you have a storage account already created , so that terraform can refer it and initialize .

Comment: To store the tfstate you need to have the storage account and container preconfigured , for terraform to be able to use it .

Comment: Thanks now i undemand, i have to hardcode those values.

Comment: i removed every thing still i am getting below error  $ terraform init

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "azurerm_storage_container.storage_acc.name": storage.AccountsClient#ListKeys: Invalid input: autorest/validation: validation failed: parameter=accountName constraint=MaxLength value="azurerm_storage_container.storage_acc.name" details: value length must be less than 
or equal to 24
│
│